# Atom: how to make newlines with snippets

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

I'm trying to create a simple snippet:

```
'.source.c':
    'prinf':
        'prefix': 'souf'
        'body': 'printf("%$1\n");'
```

The problem is: it actually makes the newline instead of writing `\n`:

```
printf("%
    ");
```

I want: `printf("%\n");`

I've also tried `\\n` in the body of the snippet, but it only writes `n`: `printf("%n");`

Do you know how to? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use four backslashes.

```coffee
'body': 'printf("%$1\\\\n");'
```

From what I can tell, the first pair are used when *setting* the snippet (c.f. `\n`), the second pair are used when *using* the snippet (c.f. `\\$1`).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but per their [docs](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/), you use a triple quotation syntax `"""`.

Their example is:

```
'.source.js':
  'if, else if, else':
    'prefix': 'ieie'
    'body': """
      if (${1:true}) {
        $2
      } else if (${3:false}) {
        $4
      } else {
        $5
      }
    """
```

It's coffee script or something. But I just wrote a `.then().catch()` using this method and it worked great.